# Where to get NSTextView dragged images reference

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView with `setImportGraphics(true)`, I can drag images there, they show up in the interface but I have no idea how to programmatically get the image (and store it) once it's been dragged.

If I call `myNSTextView.string` all I get is the text around the image, but the image seems non-existent.

Do I have to implement some methods regarding drag and drop to manage this case?

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea how to programmatically get the image (and store it) once it's been dragged.

Dropped images are added to the NSTextStorage as NSTextAttachment. So, in order to access the dropped images you should iterate over the content of the textStorage and check for attachments that conforms to image files.

> Do I have to implement some methods regarding drag and drop to manage this case

You certainly can handle the dropped files by extending NSTextView and overwriting the `- (void)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingOperation>)sender` method, if you want to go this way, I recommend you to read the [Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069-SW1) document from Apple.

Since I'm no fan of subclassing, my answer to this problem uses a Category of NSAttributedString to return a NSArray of attached images. Which can be solved with the code below:

```
#import "NSAttributedString+AttachedImages.h"

@implementation NSAttributedString (AttachedImages)


- (NSArray *)images
{
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSRange effectiveRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);

    NSTextAttachment *attachment;
    CFStringRef extension;
    CFStringRef fileUTI;

    while (NSMaxRange(effectiveRange) < self.length) {
        attachment = [self attribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName atIndex:NSMaxRange(effectiveRange) effectiveRange:&effectiveRange];

        if (attachment) {
            extension = (__bridge CFStringRef) attachment.fileWrapper.preferredFilename.pathExtension;
            fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);
            if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) {
                NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:attachment.fileWrapper.regularFileContents];
                [theImage setName:attachment.fileWrapper.preferredFilename];

                [images addObject:theImage];
            }
        }
    }

    return images.copy;
}

@end
```

If you use GIT, you can clone the code from my [Github repository](https://github.com/brunvieira/NSAttributedString-AttachedImages).

I hope it helps